# How to extract date from a string using regular expression

Tags: regex

"Posted by Higher Abc on 1/28/2014 3:01:30 AM Reference 402412"

I am new to regexp and i need to find out the date(i.e 1/28/2014) from the above string using regexp.

Can anybody help me on this. and please suggest any good site for regular expression learning.

Comment: What flavour of regexp are you using?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ has a lot of information and http://regex101.com/ is a nice little playground to try it out.

Comment: I am using normal regular expression to group it, my try was like this.."([0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})","$1" .

Answer (score 2):

`\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}` will capture the date in that string.

Or to get even more precise (and assuming a date in the present century), you could try something like this:

`[1]?\d/[123]?\d/20\d{2}`

**Explanation**:

`[1]?` will match zero or one occurrences of the number 1 (the possible beginning of a month number if the month is 10, 11, or 12).

`\d/` will match a single digit followed by a forward slash.

`[123]?` will match zero or one occurrences of the numbers 1, 2, or 3 (the possible beginnings of a two-digit day of the month).

`\d/` will match a single digit followed by a forward slash.

`20` will only match the digit 2 followed by 0.

`\d{2}` will match any two digits.

Comment: The second regex can match invalid dates like 19/39/2014

Comment: @m0nk3y True. The second answer was meant as a closer approximation. A truly exact answer would need to account for things like the different number of days in each month and leap years, but this sort of answer may go beyond the OP's more immediate needs based on their example.